Centralized Docker Image Pull and Deployment Across Multiple Environments
At present, it seems that I have to manually access each environment, pull the Docker image, and deploy it separately. This process can become repetitive and time-consuming when dealing with multiple environments
My question:
Is there a centralized method or feature within Portainer that would allow me to pull a Docker image and deploy it across multiple selected environments in one go, rather than accessing each environment individually?
Any guidance or suggestions on how to streamline this process would be greatly appreciated.
